# Can someone explain to me why '\n' doesn't register when it is used in with a function?

Tags: python, string

For context, this is the camel case #4 question from HackerRank.

I am given a multi-string such as `test`...

```
test = '''S;M;plasticCup()
C;V;mobile phone
C;C;coffee machine
'''
```

and I need to manipulate it based on several conditions (not relevant). Once I have successfully manipulated `test`, I need to return my own multi-line string `output`, which I am trying to accomplish below.

```
def feeder(user_input):
    split_total = user_input.splitlines()
    output = ''
    for element in split_total:
        output += f"{camelCase(element)} \n"
        #camelCase()` is the user-defined function that applies the "several conditions" mentioned earlier
        #code snippet for camelCase() provided at bottom of the post, in case it matters
    return output
```

```
feeder(test)
```

However, my output variable completely ignores the newline `\n`s?

```
'plastic cup \nmobilePhone \nCoffeeMachine'
```

What gives?

## I tried newline and it works here?

```
chr_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
output = ''
for element in chr_list:
    output += f"{element}\n"
print(output)
```

OUTPUT

```
a
b
c
```

## CamelCase code

```
def camelCase(user_input):
    split_ls = user_input.split(';')
    if (split_ls[0] == 'S'): #splitting
        index_of_upr, split_of_upr = [], []
        split_ls[2] = split_ls[2].replace('()', '') #remove method's ()
        for index, character in enumerate(split_ls[2]):
            if (character.isupper()):
                split_ls[2] = split_ls[2].replace(character, ' ' + character.lower())
        split_ls[2] = split_ls[2].strip()
        return split_ls[2]
    else: #combining
        split_ls[2] = split_ls[2].split(' ')
        for i in range(len(split_ls[2])):
            split_ls[2][i] = split_ls[2][i].title()
        if (split_ls[1] == 'C'): #class
            return ''.join(split_ls[2])
        else: #method,variable
            split_ls[2][0] = split_ls[2][0].lower()
            if (split_ls[1] == 'V'): #variable
                return ''.join(split_ls[2])
            else: #method
                return ''.join(split_ls[2]) + '()'
```

Thanks everyone for having a look at my code :)

Comment: "my output variable completely ignores the newline" - Well, I can see them in your string: 'plastic cup **\n**mobilePhone **\n**CoffeeMachine'. Just print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns the string. You have to print the string to view the new lines. Here:

```
print(feeder(test))
```

Outputs:

```
plastic cup 
mobilePhone 
CoffeeMachine
```

Print will evaluate the new line character and reflect it as such.

Hope this helped :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference in returning the string or printing it.

- When printing it the `\n` character does actually get shown as a newline
- With the return statement from a function it continues to be shown as `\n` in the string until you `print(string)`

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is looking at the result as a raw string vs printed.

When looking at the raw string, the `\n` new lines are escaped as `\n`

```py
'plastic cup \nmobilePhone \nCoffeeMachine'
```

While if you print it, it should interpret `\n` as to print to a new line, giving you something like this:

```py
plastic cup 
mobilePhone 
CoffeeMachine
```

Comment: thank you! this answers the question perfectly!